# how to make menu-toggle by default close

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, toggle, default-value

I am using Twitter bootstrap responsive menu (link:http://responsive.redlightblinking.com/)
According to this design, on smaller screen the menu by default should be closed. Unfortunately, when I used it in my website, the menu is open by default. Can anybody tell me why it is like this and how can I change this? 
In my project, I am using the same bootstrap.js, bootstrap.css and custom.css from the above link.Can someone tell me what function behaves as open and close so that I can change it?

Comment: for me its closed, which browser are you using

Comment: Hi shaN, even for me it is closed. But when I use that in my website, it is by default open. I want to know what triggers it to be by default closed or open so that I can change it

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed. Classes were swapped in top menu.

This was called

instead of